# Алгоритм поиска пустых ячеек произвольного размера

Tags: поиск, алгоритм, матрицы, lua

Всем привет. Я не очень силен в матане, поэтому меня интересует вопрос, как найти пустые ячейки произвольного размера (+ в произвольной таблице) + в зависимости от позиции ячеек?

Если кто не понял, то вот примеры.

false - занятые ячейки, true - пустые.

Пример 1. Нужно найти свободную ячейку 2 на 1 (высота, ширина)

```
local matrix =
{
 { true, false, false };
 { true, false, true };
};

-- matrix[1][1]-->true
-- matrix[2][1]-->true
```

Пример 2. Нужно найти свободную ячейку 2 на 2 (высота, ширина)

```
local matrix =
{
 { false, true, true };
 { true, true, true };
};

-- matrix[1][2]-->true
-- matrix[1][3]-->true
-- matrix[2][2]-->true
-- matrix[2][3]-->true
```

Пример 3. Нужно найти свободную ячейку 2 на 2 (высота, ширина)

```
local matrix =
{
 { true, true, false };
 { false, true, true };
};

-- false
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Надо пройтись по таблице двойным циклом for.

Comment: А если таблица произвольного размера? Ячеек может быть 7x8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, уже помогли на другом форуме. Вот функция
http://forum.mtasa.com/viewtopic.php?f=141&t=83292&p=757808#p757802

```
function cellfind( arr, h, w )
    local len = #arr
    h = h - 1
    w = w - 1

    for columPos, rowData in ipairs(arr ) do
        for cellPos, cellData in ipairs(rowData) do
            if cellData and not (columPos + h > len) and arr[columPos + h][cellPos + w] then
                local free = true
                for ii = columPos, columPos + h do
                    if not arr[ii][cellPos] or not free then
                        free = false
                        break
                    end

                    for jj = cellPos + 1, cellPos + w  do
                        if not arr[ii][jj] then
                            free = false
                        end
                    end
                end
                if free then print(string.format("[%d, %d] [%d, %d]", columPos, cellPos, columPos + h, cellPos + w)) end
            end
        end
    end
end
```